# What to use instead of sizeof(void)?

Tags: c, void-pointers, file-copying

I'm trying to copy a file. I'm using a borrowed code snippet, and there's a line of it which errors which confuses me.

```
int fileread = open("original.txt", O_RDONLY);
void *buffer;
buffer = malloc(sizeof(void) * size);  /*This line gives "Incomplete type not allowed."*/

int nread = read(fileread,buffer,size);

int filewrite = open("original.txt.backup",O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0644);

write(filewrite,buffer,size);

close(filewrite);
close(fileread);
```

What should I be using instead? I was thinking char*, but I want to make sure I'm understanding the process going on here.

Comment: Reserving memory for a `void *` makes no sense.

Comment: That's what I thought...but I'm terrible with C. Absolutely terrible.

Comment: @chris I just skimmed your mini-bio...why, why I ask, are you interested in learning Scheme? I'm finishing the same university program you're excited to start, and God did I hate scheme.

Comment: Well, if I get into Software Engineering, apparently they use C and C++, which turns out great for me, but if not that, CS is my next option. If I don't end up in CS, I'll probably get around to doing Haskell. It's nice to learn the functional language side of things, and Haskell seems to be popular with the other C++ people who hang around here.

Comment: Gotcha. If you're really into this stuff, you'll probably like it for sure. Can't say it doesn't give you a different perspective. As for "Software Engineering" vs "Computer Science"-- don't be fooled. As a grad, one thing I can say for sure is that if you know how to program, titles and names are just semantics. My degree is in Computer Science and I'm in second round interviews for software engineering positions. You really learn the same stuff either way.

Comment: Plus regardless of which program you're in, you'll be able to choose courses in whatever interests you. So again, it really doesn't matter very much. Both curriculums will have the fundamentals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sizeof() returns the size of your type. Honestly I think you should just change it to

```
char *buffer;
buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
```

Sizeof(void) makes zero sense

Comment: Byte is a defined type? I'm going to go with char, since they're...equivalent?

Comment: sorry mixing up my languages, yes use char

Comment: I'd prefer `char *buffer; buffer = malloc(sizeof(*buffer) * size);` so that the size will be correct even if the type that `buffer` points to is later changed.

Comment: `sizeof (char)` is 1 by definition.  `malloc(size)` is sufficient.

Comment: True, but I'd prefer to be safe just in case the data type is ever changed.

Comment: @JoshuaGreen, Don't take this as just for the sake of argument, but that will break way too much code to even consider it.

Comment: _What_ will break too much code?  Writing `malloc(sizeof(*buffer) * size)` rather than `malloc(size)` or `malloc(sizeof(char) * size)` shouldn't (in this case).

Comment: @JoshuaGreen: If it's ever changed, he still wants bytes, since that's what he's reading from the files. So if you're seriously concerned that `sizeof(char)` might ever be something other than 1, you'd need to leave it out when allocating memory for raw binary data read from a file.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to allocate a buffer of `size` bytes, and have `buffer` point to the beginning of it:

```
void *buffer = malloc(size);
if (buffer == NULL) {
    /* allocation failed */
}
/* ... */
```

But if you want to do something with the data in the buffer, it will need to have a valid type.  An array of `unsigned char` is a common way to manage buffers of arbitrary contents:

```
unsigned char *buffer = malloc(size);
/* as above */
```

Comment: +1 for the `NULL` check, though I still prefer `malloc(sizeof(*buffer) * size)` in case "we" ever decide to store a larger data type while still wanting `size` to denote the number of elements.